# How to count number of records from specific cateogry using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display number of records from specific categories.

Just like stackoverflow showing here in related tags section.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions

javascript × 943089
java × 926620
c# × 848261
php × 807008
```

I am using this code.

```
<?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM data where category = 'android'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo 'Android = '.$row['num'].'<br>';
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM data where category = 'ajax'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo 'Ajax = '.$row['tot'].'<br>';
    }   

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as det FROM data where category = 'php'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo 'PHP = '.$row['det'].'<br>';
    }

?>
```

Its working fine but I don't want to use so many SQL queries.

How to achieve this using single SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with  `group by` clause

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT category, COUNT(*) as num FROM data where category in ( `PHP`, `MYSQL`, `JAVA`, `AJAX`  ) group by category");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $row['category'] . ' = '.$row['num'].'<br>';
 }
```

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge but its showing all categories and number of records, as i want to display only specific one's. Just like PHP = 10, MYSQL = 20

Comment: I am sorry i meant to say I just want to use specific categories like PHP, MYSQL, JAVA, AJAX so query will display how many records each category has. I want to write categories by my own.

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge it works and sorry I can't vote you up as I am in low reputation, but thanks again

Comment: I think you can accepet the answer